How do i change the type of the modal text input?
This code serve the purpose to check if the user's input premium code in the premium code array. Though, the type of modal textinput is <class 'discord.ui.text_input.TextInput'>, while i need it to be in str for it to work. And yes, i tried str(), it still doesn't work. How do i compare values ignoring its type or how do i change discord.ui.text_input.TextInput type to string? Any help?
class Mymodal(ui.Modal, title="Be an elite user"):
  code = ui.TextInput(label="Enter code", placeholder="Include capitals and dashes.", style=discord.TextStyle.short)
  async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    refresh()
    print(type(self.code))
    if self.code in client.monthly_codes:
      if interaction.user.id in client.monthly_user or interaction.user.id in client.yearly_user:
        if interaction.user.id in client.yearly_user:
          premium_status = "Yearly"
        else:
          premium_status = "Monthly"

I tried:
if str(self.code) in client.monthly_codes:
expecting:
for it to works:
result:
it doesn't

In order to get the value of a TextInput, simple use the value property. In your case, you can simply do self.code.value.
Reference: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=textinput#discord.TextInput.value

but value here returns the default value of the textinput, default value here means that, the initial text that appears in the box that users can consider for their input and they can delete it. Do you understand what i mean?

to make it simpler, lets say a user open the modal and this is what they will see
Are you satisfied with the service:
Yes/No
Here the yes/no aren't placeholder, it can be deleted, this is what value or default returns

I really don't understand? value will return the value of the TextInput. You're trying to get the value of code in your on_submit, meaning upon the submission of the modal, code.value will be populated with whatever the user inputted.
